# How to make Icecast audio stream all browser compatible?

Tags: apache, html5-audio, audio-streaming, icecast, internet-radio

I am trying to build a little radio station using Icecast.
Currently, it is accessible by an HTTP webpage including the `<audio>` tag which uses the Icecast mount point as audio source a.k.a. `<source>` tag.
While from a PC all this works fine with Google Chrome, Safari seems to not accept the stream (it is automatically downloaded as file). Similar issue for mobile browsers (no audio when pressing play).
Is it possible to solve this issue, making the audio tag compatible with all the browser currently available? If yes, how?

#### April 23rd Update

As suggested, I am going to update the question by adding the HTML structure of the test webpage where I am still facing this issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Live Streming Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Live streaming test webpage</h1>
    <div id="audiowrap">
      <audio preload controls controlsList="nodownload">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio
        <source src="http://192.168.1.192:8000/live-streaming" type="audio/ogg">
      </audio>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If it could be useful, I am using Apache to manage HTTP requests, and this is part of the configuration file dedicated to that test page:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.1.192
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/<dir_with_the_index.html_file_above>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, here are also the main directives of the `icecast.xml` configuration file:

```
<hostname>localhost</hostname>
<listen-socket>
    <port>8000</port>
</listen-socket>
```

Comment: The behavior you're describing basically can't happen.  You undoubtedly have some invalid HTML or something, with some link to the stream URL.  Show us the HTML you're trying to use.  A simple `<audio>` tag *does* work with SHOUTcast/Icecast streams.

Comment: @Brad, thanks for your suggestion. I have just updated the question.

Comment: When you say your stream is "automatically downloaded as file", what do you mean, specifically?  There's nothing in this HTML that does this.  Are you saying that when you open your stream URL in a new tab, this happens?  What codecs are you using?  Ogg in general isn't supported everywhere.

Comment: [This](https://paste.pics/e819c0a550dfd3c4d99cda312e19949d) is a screenshot of the page after pressing the Play button (no audio to main output), while [this](https://paste.pics/987662f2936f685be7eaedd7000e5e1b) is what happens when trying to reach the Icecast stream (`http://192.168.1.192:8000/live-streaming`).

Comment: And, if you try something like a basic MP3 stream?

Comment: I've added a new `<source type="audio/mpeg"/>` element and the audio stream seems to work fine on all devices, even from mobiles. Thanks again for the suggestion.